# SSH heredoc: bash prompt

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I am attempting to write a shell script which SSHs into a server and then prompts the user to enter a file/folder.

```
ssh $SERVER <<EOF
cd downloads/
read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " FILEPATH
echo $FILEPATH
eval FILEPATH="$FILEPATH"

echo "Downloading $FILEPATH to $CLIENT"
EOF
```

I am using heredoc instead of double quotes after the SSH to execute these commands because my shell script is rather large and I don't want to be escaping every double quote.

When I was using double quotes, the prompt worked fine. However, now that I am using heredoc, the prompt no longer works.

What can I do to get the prompt to work with heredoc? And if not, is there any way I layout my script so that the prompt does work without wrapping everything in double quotes and escaping, like so:

```
ssh $SERVER "
cd downloads/
read -e -p \"Enter the path to the file: \" FILEPATH
echo $FILEPATH
eval FILEPATH=\"$FILEPATH\"

echo \"Downloading $FILEPATH to $CLIENT\"
exit
"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need any variables from the client, why not try - and `ssh -t` might be useful.

```
export CLIENT=me 

CMDS=$(cat <<CMD 
cd downloads/ 
read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " FILEPATH 
echo \$FILEPATH 
eval FILEPATH="\$FILEPATH" 

echo "Downloading \$FILEPATH to $CLIENT" 
CMD 
) 

ssh localhost -t "$CMDS"
```

Note that if your only issue with double-quotes is escaping, and you do not plan on
using `'` single quotes in your script, then you can ust do this:

```
ssh -t $SERVER '
# your script, unescaped.
# if you want access to a locally defined variable,
echo "CLIENT is '$CLIENT'."
'
```

Comment: Changing it to `<<'EOF'` just takes me to the bash prompt inside of the SSH server. What I actually meant by 'prompt' is this: `read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " FILEPATH` – the script should prompt the user for a file.

Comment: I was initially using single quotes, but then I can't access variables such as `$CLIENT`, which was defined before the SSH command.

Comment: Added a suggestion about un-escaping single quotes. ugly, but wonder if it works for you?

Comment: Your suggestion about unescaping single quotes works. Could be uglier! Reckon this is the best I’ll get?

Comment: No... try adding `-t` to the `ssh`?

Comment: Now I need to use single quotes inside (see line 22): http://hastebin.com/pekegexiso.bash – tried escaping them but I don't think that will work like that.

Comment: Just updated my first suggestion - you'll have to escape remote (server-side) vars using `\$varname` while leaving locally declared variables as they are.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21330/discussion-between-faiz-and-oliver-joseph-ash)

Answer (score 7):

To make it work with a heredoc, it should be sufficient to invoke `bash`, or whatever shell you want to use on the remote server. Like so:

```
ssh $SERVER bash <<EOF
cd downloads/
read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " FILEPATH
echo $FILEPATH
eval FILEPATH="$FILEPATH"

echo "Downloading $FILEPATH to $CLIENT"
EOF
```

Note that you probably want to escape the `$` on `FILEPATH`, since currently that will be interpolated by the local shell rather than the remote shell.

Answer (score 3):

this works, tab completion on the host works.

```
var=$(cat<<EOF
read -e -p Path pname;
echo \$pname;
hostname;
echo \$pname;
cd \$pname;
pwd;
touch THIS ;
exit;
EOF
)

ssh -t NODE $var
```

on mine this creates the file THIS in the prompted for directory.

Comment: By prompt I mean this: `read -e -p \"Enter the path to the file: \" FILEPATH`

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to work:

```
T=$(tty) ; bash <<XXX
echo Hi "$T"
read p <$T
echo p: \$p
echo Bye
XXX
```

Comment: How would an SSH equivalent of that look?