# sed not working on remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, sed

I'm trying to run a script on a remote server like so:

```
ssh root@cnc-02 'bash -c "
      echo $SHELL;
      cd /home/bldadmin/patch;
      pwd;
      echo '$int_ver_cnc';
      echo '$rev_ver_cnc';
      echo '$pre_ver_cnc';
      cp -Rf RP_'$pre_ver_cnc'-'$int_ver_cnc' RP_'$int_ver_cnc'-'$rev_ver_cnc';
      cd /home/bldadmin/patch/RP_'$int_ver_cnc'-'$rev_ver_cnc'/CSCONsap/data/twoway/manual;
      rm rulePkg.zip;
      mv cncrules-CNC60Test-1.48.0-1.49.0.zip rulePkg.zip;
      cd /home/bldadmin/patch/RP_'$int_ver_cnc'-'$rev_ver_cnc';
      find . -name install.sh.orig;
      sed -e 's/^\(patchid=\)\(.*\)/\1\"1.47.0-1.48.0\"/g' -e 's/^\(fromVersion=\)\(.*\)/\1\"1.47.0\"/g' -e 's/^\(toVersion=\)\(.*\)/\1\"1.48.0\"/g' install.sh.orig >newfile.sh.orig;
"'
```

This is my script on my local machine. It will SSH to a remote machine and execute a list of commands. All the commands are executing but `sed` is not working. I'm getting the below error

```
"bash: -c: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `(' bash: -c:
line 14: `      sed -e s/^(patchid=)(.*)/11.47.0-1.48.0/g -e
s/^(fromVersion=)(.*)/11.47.0/g -e s/^(toVersion=)(.*)/11.48.0/g
install.sh.orig >newfile.sh.orig;' "
```

The `sed` command when executed locally is working fine, I don't know what I am missing?

Comment: You have quoting issues, `bash` thinks you terminated the double-quoted text in the middle of your sed script.

Comment: I think you might need to use a here document to escape the quotes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934280/ssh-heredoc-bash-prompt

Answer (score 4):

Instead of getting in a quoting headache save your script into a file `script.sh` 
 *(use a sensible descriptive name)* and run:

```
$ ssh root@cnc-02 'bash -s' < script.sh
```